# How to incorporate nested dataframe groupby loops in a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, recursion

I am having trouble creating a recursive function that can do nested loops. Here is an example.
Let's say I have a dataframe as below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A    1    Y    10
A    1    Y    19
A    1    N    20
A    2    Y    21
A    3    N    22
C    3    N    23
```

I wanted to groupby col1,col2,col3 and then calculate the sum of col4. A normal block of code would look like this.

```
for code,val in df.groupby(by='col1'):
    for codee,vall in val.groupby(by='col2'):
        for codeee,valll in vall.groupby(by='col3):
            answer=sum(valll['col4'])
```

But I wanted to create a recursive function to do the task. Here is what I got so far.

```
real=[]
def groupby_recurse(data, levels):
    layer = len(levels)
    if layer >= 1:
        for code, val in data.groupby(by=levels[-layer]):
            groupby_recurse(val, levels[(-layer + 1):])
    else:
        real.append(sum(data['col4']))
    return real

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 'Y', 10], ['A', 1, 'Y', 19], ['A', 1, 'N', 20], ['A', 2, 'Y', 21],
                   ['A', 2, 'Y', 22], ['C', 3, 'N', 23]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
groupby_recurse(df, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

This function has a serious problem. When layer=2, -layer+1=-1, I am at the last element of my groupby key list, but going to the next round, when layer=1 and -layer+1=0, it suddenly jumps to the first element of the groupby key list and it goes on forever. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated. Cheers.

expected output is a list containing all of the sum values.
the first value would be 29.Because after grouping all three columns, df would look like this

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
    A    1    Y    10
    A    1    Y    19
```

next would be 20 because after grouping df would look like this.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A    1    N    20
```

and then it would be 21.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A    2    Y    21
```

....
The end result would be [29,20,21,22,23]. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: show your expected output dataframe

Comment: YOLO provide the right answer, your example is wrong at the end, it will be 43 not 21 for `A,2,Y,21` and `A,2,Y,22`

Comment: I just realised my example df at the very top is different from the one in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion, simply do:

```
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['col4'].sum().reset_index()
```